# Voter analysis on the type of Democratic candidate for the 2020 US Election

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, reference-request

I was watching Fox News[(click here for the video and go to around 4:27)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VxcghFai3ks) and the female anchor was quoting a voter analysis as below-

> It’s very important to pick the candidate who can beat Donald Trump
>   those that say that is the most important, 86%  to picking a strong
>   leader ranks high at 82%, those that care about people 67%.

What is the source of this analysis?

I searched google but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 4):

It's from their "Voter Analysis" based on surveys conducted by [NORC at the University of Chicago](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NORC_at_the_University_of_Chicago), an independent research firm.

Methodology Statement:

> The Fox News Voter Analysis, conducted in partnership with the
>   Associated Press, provides a comprehensive look at voting behavior,
>   opinions and preferences as America votes. It is based on surveys of
>   the American electorate conducted by NORC at the University of
>   Chicago. For the 2020 Democratic presidential primaries and caucuses,
>   the FNVA results are based on interviews with a random sample of
>   registered voters drawn from state voter files. In select states,
>   these probability sample results are supplemented by interviews with
>   self-identified registered voters recruited from nonprobability online
>   panels. The FNVA methodology captures last-minute voter trends, which
>   are of particular importance in the early caucuses and primaries, as
>   well as the sentiments and behavior of early and absentee voters, who
>   are significant on Super Tuesday and other later primaries.

Source: https://www.foxnews.com/elections/2020/primary-results/voter-analysis?state=NH